# What would be the running time of an algorithm that combines mergeSort and heapsort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, mergesort, heapsort

I have been given this problem that asks to compute the worst case running time of an algorithm that's exactly like mergeSort, but one of the two recursive calls is substituted by Heapsort.

So, I know that dividing in mergesort takes constant time and that merging is O(n). Heapsort takes O(nlogn).
This is what I came up with: T(n) = 2T(n/2) + O((n/2)logn)+ O(n).
I have some doubts about the O((n/2)logn) part. Is it n or n/2? I wrote n/2 because I'm doing heapsort only on half of the array, but I'm not sure that's correct

Answer (score 0):

The question asks about running time, but should it be asking about time complexity?

Since recursion is mentioned, this is a question about top down merge sort (as opposed to bottom up merge sort).

With the code written as described, since heap sort is not recursive, recursion only occurs on one of each of the split sub-arrays. Heap sort will be called to sort sub-arrays of size n/2, n/4, n/8, n/16, ... , and no merging takes place until two sub-arrays of size 1 are the result of the recursive splitting. In the simple case where array size is a power of 2, then "merge sort" is only used for a single element, the rest of the sub-arrays of size {1, 2, 4, 8, ..., n/8, n/4, n/2} are sorted by heap sort and then merged.

Since heap sort is slower than merge sort, then running time will be longer, but time complexity remains at O(n log(n)) since constant or lower term factors are ignored for time complexity.

Comment: Ok! Thanks! So the overall time complexity is O(nlogn)??

Comment: @yoyo_24 - Since both heap and merge have time complexity O(n log(n)), any mix of the two will also have time complexity O(n log(n)), although the running time will vary, due to constants and lower order terms that are ignored by big O time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Let’s work out what the recurrence relation should be in this case. Here, we’re

- splitting the array in half,
- recursively sorting one half (T(n / 2)),
- heapsorting one half (O(n log n)), and then
- merging the two halves together (O(n)).

That gives us this recurrence relation:

> T(n) = T(n / 2) + O(n log n).

Why is this O(n log n) and not, say, O((n / 2) log (n / 2))? The reason is that big-O notation munches up constant factors, so O(n log n) expresses the same asymptotic growth rate as O((n / 2) log (n / 2)). And why isn’t there a coefficient of 2 on the T(n / 2)? It’s because we’re only making one recursive call; remember that the other call was replaced by heapsort.

All that’s left to do now is to solve this recurrence. It does indeed work out to O(n log n), and I’ll leave it to you to decide how you want to show this. The iteration method is a great option here.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was extremely helpful. Just one question: why don’t you consider the merging contribution in the recurrence?